# Rest Web Services using Spring are not invoked in weblogic 12.2.1

Tags: spring, rest, java-8, weblogic12c

We are looking at upgrading our application to **Weblogic 12.2.1**. The server comes up properly. But we are not able to invoke any of the web-services. They are written using Spring. Also we are using JDK 8.

The error message that comes up in the logs is:

> org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/test/components] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher' [noHandlerFound:1120 {}]

The issue only comes when we install the application using an installer. **When we deploy the application in our development environment, the issue does not arise.** We are able to invoke the services successfully.

We have compared the classpath in the installer as well as the development, they are the same.

Dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<beans
xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="test" />

<bean id="localeResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
    <property name="defaultLocale" value="en" />
</bean>

<bean id="mvcConfigurationBeanPostProcessor"
      class="com.jda.webworks.publicapi.common.SpringMvcConfigBeanPostProcessor">
</bean>

<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:message-converters register-defaults="false">
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter" />
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter" />
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter" />
    </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>

<!-- enable the configuration of app server transactional behavior based on annotations -->
<tx:annotation-driven/>
<tx:jta-transaction-manager/>

<!-- Create instance of transaction template for programmatic transaction manipulation -->
<bean id="transactionTemplate" class="org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager"></property>
</bean>
```

We tried adding `<mvc:default-servlet-handler />` also. But that did not help.

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<!--
<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/log4j.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
-->

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!--
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
</listener>
-->

<session-config>
    <session-timeout>1</session-timeout>
</session-config>

<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>WebWORKS RESTful Services</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
        <http-method>PUT</http-method>
        <http-method>DELETE</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>NetworksUsers</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    <realm-name>default</realm-name>
</login-config>
<security-role>
    <role-name>NetworksUsers</role-name>
</security-role>
```

Please give us any pointers to help resolve the issue.

Comment: can you add web.xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have raised a case with Oracle. In the meanwhile, we found a workaround for the above problem.

This seems to work if the rest classes are available **under WEB-INF/classes or WEB-INF/lib**. Previously, we had the classes load from a "higher" classloader, from the ear/lib (set through application.xml as lib) and then we see the issue.
And of course, in WLS 12.1.3, we never had any issues. The .jar containing the REST classes were only in ear/lib and not in WEB-INF of the WAR.